# How do I get the ecpaped double quotes to print in a Jenkins shared library file? (groovy internpolation issue)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

The goal is to return a string like.

```sh
git commit --all --message="Automated version bump to 1.0.0" --author="Jenkins <louie@example.com>"
```

This works as pure groovy as in the console with:

```
String nextVersion = "1.0.0"
String commitAuthor = 'Jenkins <louie@example.com>'
String commitFiles = '--all'
String commitMessage = "Automated version bump to $nextVersion"

println("git commit $commitFiles --message=\"$commitMessage\" --author=\"$commitAuthor\"")
```

However when I run it in side of an sh() step in a jenkins shared library file like this:

```
def call(
  String nextVersion = '1.0.0'
  String commitAuthor = 'Jenkins <louie@.com>',
  String commitFiles = '--all'
) {

    String commitMessage = "Automated version bump to $nextVersion"

    sh(
      label: 'Committing code changes if any made to release branch',
      script: "git commit $commitFiles --message=\"$commitMessage\" --author=\"$commitAuthor""
    )
}
```

It returns:

```sh
git commit --all --message=Automated version bump to  --author=Jenkins <louie@example.com>
```

Where are my quotes going? what do I need to do? I have also tried using ``` adn """ versions of this with the different Interpolation methods

Comment: Escaping the quotes like that in the shell step method is instructing the shell interpreter to resolve those variables instead of resolving them in Groovy with the quotes around them. You may need to double escape.

Comment: Try single quotes `script: "git commit $commitFiles --message='$commitMessage' --author='$commitAuthor'"`?